# Association between continuous input and categorical output

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression, correlation

I have two independent continuous variables like Age, Price and an outcome variable like purchased or not purchased

Now, which test should I use to ascertain the association of continuous input variable with categorical outcome variable?

Comment: isn't like a classic differential test ? if you have normalized distributed feature one can use t-test, otherwise sth like wilcoxon - the result will be whether the continues value is enriched in one group that the other ?!

Comment: Can't we use point biseral corelation?

Comment: your question is more statistical - I recommend to consult in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ - meanwhile : correlation coefficients or coefficients from logistic regression  only give you the "effect size" not the level of significance. you have used term : "association" which implies you are after finding the level of significance :-) in stat words matter.

Comment: @user702846 - let's I have one binary variable and continuous variable  but the values for continuous variable are only very few. Meaning, ex: in the whole column, only 5 values keep repeating for continuous variable. In this case, can I consider them as categorical (because oy 5 unique values/levels) and apply chi-square test for association?

Comment: technically you can - but what it means and how to interpret I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Try logistic regression. The sigmoid function and its variants allow for conversion of continuous inputs into a binary outcome variable.

Comment: Can log reg work fpr just 1 input variable and 1 outpit variable?

Comment: cant we use point biseral corelation? Upvoted for thehelp

Comment: Perhaps yes, but also try out f-classif, mutual-info-classif under sklearn.feature_selection